# Pass PHP variables from text fields to bash script and execute

Tags: php

I would like to create web app, which have 2 text fields and submit button, which execute bash script and use text from this two fields as variables.

I created main page as **main.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>

<form name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="">
</form>


<form name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="subject2" id="subject2" value="">
</form>

<form>
<input class="col btn btn-dark-moon btn-rounded" type="button" value="run bash script" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost/run_bash.php'" />
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, two text fields and button for execution of run_bash.php file.

**run_bash.php** file looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'main.php';
$num = $_GET['subject'];
$text = $_GET['subject2'];

$num = escapeshellarg($num);
$text = escapeshellarg($text);

$output = shell_exec("bash code.sh $num $text 2>&1");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I am trying to get text from text fields in `main.php` and use it as variable `$num` and `$text` in bash script (code.sh).

Bash scrip **code.sh** for example looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
var2=$2
echo $var1 $var2
```

So at the end, I would like, that when I put text in a field 1 (e.g. Hello) and field 2 (e.g. Hello world), I get output: Hello Hello World

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to direct the form to the PHP script with the `action` property.  Assuming that `main.php` is in the same directory as `run_bash.php` (I didn't see the `onclick` at first, that may work):

You also need all controls in the same form in `main.php`:

```
<form name="form" action="run_bash.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="">
    <input type="text" name="subject2" id="subject2" value="">
    <input class="col btn btn-dark-moon btn-rounded" type="button" value="run bash script" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost/run_bash.php'" />
</form>
```

And then check if submitted with text in the PHP:

```
<?php
include 'main.php';
if(isset($_GET['subject'], $_GET['subject2'])) { //or !empty() if text is required
// if(!empty($_GET['subject']) && !empty($_GET['subject2'])) {
    $num = $_GET['subject'];
    $text = $_GET['subject2'];
    
    $num = escapeshellarg($num);
    $text = escapeshellarg($text);
    
    $output = shell_exec("bash code.sh $num $text 2>&1");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}
?>
```

Also, `bash code.sh` assumes that it is in the same directory as well.  If not then `bash /path/to/the/code.sh`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still does not work.

Comment: Then you'll need debugging info like do the `$_GET` vars display on run_bash.php, does the sh script run.

Comment: if I run run_bash script over terminal I get error: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: subject in /var/www/html/run_bash.php on line 3
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: subject2 in /var/www/html/run_bash.php on line 4

Comment: Edited...  You need 1 form and the `onclick` may work I missed it.

Comment: I edit my code as you suggested. But I still have problem in run_bash.php code. Because I am getting error Undefined index for line 3 and 4 where I am trying to define variables.

Comment: No problem. But still does not work. As well if I execute run_bash.php in terminal I only get html code from part include 'main.php'. But at least I do not get error. But I also do not get bash script output.

Answer (score 0):

ok, Finally I solved the problem.

**run_bash.php** file was changed to:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['subject'], $_GET['subject2'])) {

    $num = $_GET['subject'];
    $text = $_GET['subject2'];

    $num = escapeshellarg($num);
    $text = escapeshellarg($text);

    $command = 'bash code.sh ' . $num . ' ' . $text;
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

}
?>
```

As well I changed text fields form in **main.php** to:

```
<form action="run_bash.php" method="get">
Field 1 <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
Field 2 <input type="text" name="subject2"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Run bash script">
</form>
```